# new column created has incorrect values

Tags: python, loops, variables, apply

I have two colums a and b, both are binary variables.

```
    a b
    1 1
    0 1
    1 1
    0 0
    0 0
...
    1 1
    0 1
    1 0
    0 0
    0 0
```

I need to create a new variable c after checking some conditions as below:

```
def test_func(data):
    if data['a'] == 0 & data['b'] == 0:
        return 1;
    if data['a'] == 0 & data['b'] == 1:
        return 2;
    if data['a'] == 1 & data['b'] == 0:
        return 3;
    if data['a'] == 1 & data['b'] == 1:
        return 4;
    else:
        return 0

data['c'] = data.apply(test_func, axis=1)
print(data['c'] )
```

But I am getting value  1 and 4 only in new column c, also I got value 0. Actualy, there are all four combinations (and there is no combination to get 0). But not getting them in new column c. May I know how to do this properly?

```
Desired output:
    a b c
    1 1 4
    0 1 2
    1 1 4
    0 0 1
    0 0 1
...
    1 1 4
    0 1 2
    1 0 3 
    0 0 1
    0 0 1


But what i got:
        a b c
        1 1 4
        0 1 1
        1 1 4
        0 0 1
        0 0 1
    ...
        1 1 4
        0 1 1
        1 0 0 
        0 0 1
        0 0 1
```

Comment: Could you please add a reproducible example? That would be just a simplified or mock version of your data.

Comment: yes! I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue in what you're trying to do comes from using `&` in your code, when I believe what you want is `and`. These 2 are not the same in python (more info/examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/#:%7E:text=and%20is%20a%20Logical%20AND,performs%20bit%20by%20bit%20operation.&text=This%20is%20because%20%27and%27%20tests,the%20result%20of%20both%20statements.)) but basically `and` checks if both statements evaluate to `True` whereas `&` is a bitwise operator.

So, try changing your code to:

```
def test_func(data):
    if data['a'] == 0 and data['b'] == 0:
        return 1;
    if data['a'] == 0 and data['b'] == 1:
        return 2;
    if data['a'] == 1 and data['b'] == 0:
        return 3;
    if data['a'] == 1 and data['b'] == 1:
        return 4;
    else:
        return 0
```

On a side note, you should try to avoid so many return statements in one function as it can get very confusing. You could replace it with, for example, a `result` variable that you change in each `if` block, and also changing your individual `if` statements to also use `elif`.

My suggestion for this basic example would be:

```
def test_func(data):
    result = 0

    if data['a'] == 0 and data['b'] == 0:
        result = 1
    elif data['a'] == 0 and data['b'] == 1:
        result = 2
    elif data['a'] == 1 and data['b'] == 0:
        result = 3
    elif data['a'] == 1 and data['b'] == 1:
        result = 4
    
    return result
```

Comment: Yeah.. That was the problem :D

Answer (score 2):

You can still use & if you use parenthesis

```
def test_func(x):
    if ((x.a==0)&(x.b==0)):
        return 1;
    if ((x.a==0)&(x.b==1)):
        return 2;
    if ((x.a==1)&(x.b==0)):
        return 3;
    if ((x.a==1)&(x.b==1)):
        return 4;
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Is data a dictionary? From your notation it appears that way.
What is the apply(func, val) method defined?
Assuming you have a dictionary data like {"a":1, "b":1} or any combination of 1 and 0 for a and b, using your function would be:

```
data={"a":1, "b":0} #for example
def test_func(*args):
    if data['a'] == 0 and data['b'] == 0:
        return 1
    elif data['a'] == 0 and data['b'] == 1:
        return 2
    elif data['a'] == 1 and data['b'] == 0:
        return 3
    elif data['a'] == 1 and data['b'] == 1:
        return 4
    else:
        return 0

data["c"]=test_func(data)
print(data["c"])
```